# string.at if statement doesn't return anything

Tags: c++

I'm trying to add a period to an inputted string if there isn't one at the end.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout<<"Type something\n";
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);
    string period = ".";
    if (input.at(input.length()) == period.at(1)) {
    cout<<"you entered"<<input;
    } else {
    cout<<"you entered"<<input<<".";
    }
}
```

It was supposed to add a period but ended up printing nothing. Anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Do note that C++ use 0 based indexes.  Both of your calls to `at` have an off by one error.  You should still be getting something printed though.

Comment: For example, if your string has two characters, they have indices 0 and 1. `input.at(input.length())` is basically always going to be out of bounds for any common C++ container.

Comment: @NathanOliver Should have been an exception

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're right.  I thought maybe they changed it since `string[string.size()]` is valid but they didn't

Comment: @NathanOliver Indeed - had the same thought; had to check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked it for the character at position `1`, which is the *second* character, because indexes start at zero. But there's only one character!

You have the same problem on the other side of the `==`.

Both cases will trigger [an exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at).

You don't need a string for that comparison anyway. I'd do this:

```
const char delimiter = '.';
if (!input.empty() && input.back() == delimiter)
   ...
```

Or, frankly, just do the comparison directly:

```
if (!input.empty() && input.back() == '.')
   ...
```

which is self-explanatory enough.